# How can I trigger a shell script and run in background (async) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a shell script named test.sh.  How can I trigger the test.sh from Ruby?

I want test.sh to run as a background process, what means in Ruby it is a ansync call.

STDERR and STDOUT also need to be written to a specific file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

@TanzeebKhalili's answer works, but you might consider [Kernel.spawn()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn), which doesn't wait for the process to return:

```
pid = spawn("./test.sh")
Process.detach(pid)
```

Note that, according to the documentation, whether you use `spawn()` or manually `fork()` and `system()`, you should grab the PID and either `Process.detach()` or `Process.wait()` before exiting.

Regarding redirecting standard error and output, that's easy with `spawn()`:

```
pid = spawn("./test.sh", :out => "test.out", :err => "test.err")
Process.detach(pid)
```

Comment: Nice, also works in windows ! with multiple processes that write to test.out some lines are garbled though

Comment: @peter Yeah, doing buffered writes to the same file simultaneously from multiple processes would indeed garble some lines.  There are a number of solutions to that problem, but the simplest is just writing to a separate file from each process.  Otherwise you'd probably want a separate process to multiplex the output.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
Process.fork { system "./test.sh" }
```

Won't work on windows, for which you can use threading.

Answer (score 0):

I think `IO.popopen` also deserves a mention here. Something like this would append the output from multiple runs of the command. to `stdout.log` and `stderr.log`

```
open('stdout.log', 'a') { |file|
  file.puts(
      IO.popen(["./test.sh"], :err => ["stderr.log", "a"]) { |result| 
          result.read 
      }
  )
end
```