# Ruby run external program stops script

Tags: ruby, windows, system, popen3

I have a ruby script that midway through I need it to run another program.

After running the program the rest of the script doesnt get run. For example:

```
# some ruby that gets run

exe = "Something.exe"
system(exe)

# some ruby that doesnt run
```

I have also tried using `Open3.popen2e(cmd)` and `Open3.popen3(cmd)` but its the same.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here and how to fix it?

note: I'm using windows

Comment: Does your Something.exe complete its execution? It seems like if your ruby script is waiting for the command to be completed before to continue

Comment: The program stay running in the background, so really i dont want ruby to wait, i just want it to send the command and carry on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run `Something.exe` in a new Thread:

`Thread.new { system("Something.exe") }`

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to run your `System.exe` asynchronously and continue without waiting it to be finished, you could use spawn or multithreading.

```
pid = spawn('System.exe')
Process.detach(pid)
```

According to this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11983570/5687152), this should work on Windows as well (while `fork` or other methods don't).

In [this article](http://ujihisa.blogspot.it/2010/03/how-to-run-external-command.html) you can find several examples using `system`,  `exec`, `fork`, `spawn` and `Thread` on Unix.

I cannot reproduce it, but it could be worth to see if using `system("start System.exe")` works on windows like `system("cmd &")` works on UNIX. You can refer to start documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_examples).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I used `spawn` from a Ruby program running on WSL to launch `djv` (a native Windows program). The Ruby program exits soon after, and `djv` continues. Here is the code:

```rb
realpath = File.realpath copy_filename
windows_path = `wslpath -m '#{realpath}'`.chomp
spawn 'cmd.exe', '/c',
      "C:\\Program Files\\DJV2\\bin\\djv.com",
      windows_path
```